# Square Register app is not checking authorized clientId anymore

Tags: square-connect

Somehow the Square Register app stopped to check granted permissions through oAuth process (RegisterApi.ERROR_UNAUTHORIZED_CLIENT_ID) in Android, meaning that any app could start issuing transactions on merchant's behalf.

Also https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/register-api-android/ does not mention how to manage this situation as it was before.

Any ideas about what could happened/changed?

Thanks in advance,

Federico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Square recently removed the OAuth requirement for Register API applications for iOS and Android. You still have the authorization process of logging into the Square Register App, and of course downloading the app to your device.